# How we can make an div element with scroll, to have vertical scrollbar top position 100px?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How we can make an div element with scroll, to have vertical scrollbar top position 100px?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createRef } from "react";

const DatePicker = () => {
  const myRef = createRef();

  const [openToDateNew, setOpenToDate] = useState(openToDate)

  const handleScrollBottom = () => {
    console.log("reached bottom")
    setOpenToDate(new Date(openToDateNew + 365 * 864e5));
    const node = myRef.current;
    node.scrollTop = 100;
  }

  const handleScrollTop = () => {
    console.log("reached Top")
    setOpenToDate(new Date(openToDateNew - 365 * 864e5));
  }

  return (
    <ReactScrollDetector
      debounceTime={200}
      accuracy={50}
      onScrollBottom={handleScrollBottom}
      onScrollTop={handleScrollTop}>
      <div ref={myRef} style={{ minHeight: "300px", maxHeight: "300px", overflow: "auto" }}>

      </div>
    </ReactScrollDetector>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
   <div ref={myRef} style={{ height: "300px", overflowY: "scroll" }}>

  </div>
```

after 300 px this will be scrollable or you can set height as per your requirement

Comment: My div has fixed height .there will be always scrollbar .I want the vertical scrollbar position 100px from top

Comment: yes we implement scroll fr particular height when height or width exceed scroll show. . i think just change scroll:'auto' to overflowY:' scroll'

Comment: No i am talking about offset for vertical scrollbar

Comment: yes it works for offset did you try overflowY:'scroll' ?